# Reactjs component with onClick and with update at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started Reactjs and i have this show/hide component with a parent div which shows her child(a textbox) when clicked, it works, but the problem is I want the parent div to be changed as I type in the child(textbox). . . can you help me?

```
"use strict";

var Child = React.createClass({
displayName: "Child",

getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
return { txt: "" };
},

updateTxt: function updateTxt(e) {
  this.setState({ txt: e.this.target });
},

render: function render() {
  return React.createElement(
      "div",
      null,
      React.createElement("input", { type: "text", onChange: this.updateTxt })
  );
 }
});

var ShowHide = React.createClass({
  displayName: "ShowHide",

getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
  return { txt: "Wilbert", childVisible: false };
},

render: function render() {
  return React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  React.createElement(
     "div",
     {onClick: this.onClick, update:this.updateTxt},
     this.state.txt
  ),
   this.state.childVisible ? React.createElement(Child, null) : null
 );
},

 onClick: function onClick() {
     this.setState({ childVisible: !this.state.childVisible });
   }
 });

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
   "div",
  { "className": null, id: null },
  React.createElement(ShowHide, null)),
  document.getElementById('content')
));
```

Comment: You need to get the `value` of your input in the `updateTxt` function: `this.setState({ txt: e.target.value });`

Comment: what should i change with that function sir?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing value attribute.

```
render: function render() {
  return React.createElement(
      "div",
      null,
      React.createElement("input", { type: "text",value={this.state.txt} onChange: this.updateTxt })
  );
 }
})
```